# React Routing Issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am fresh on react, and recently building my own portfolio website. However, I found an issue for when I'm routing.
This is my router:

```
 <Switch>
     <Route exact path='/project' component={ProjectDefault}/>
     <Route path='/project/:id' component={ProjectDetail}/>
 </Switch>
```

And this is my ProjectDetail Component:

```
export const ProjectDetail = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="project-detail w3-animate-zoom">
            <div className="col-lg-12 project-detail-header">
                <h2 className="name text-white">{project.name}</h2>
                <hr className="split-line"/>
                <h4 className="skills text-white"
                             {project.description}</h4>
                <h4 className="skills text-black">Developed With</h4>
                <h4 className="skills text-white">{project.tech}</h4>
            </div>
        </div>

    )
}
```

It is working fine so far, however, when I try to change my ProjectDetail Component to this:

```
export class ProjectDetail extends React.Component {
        constructor(){super();...//setting state}
        render() {
            return (
            <div className="project-detail w3-animate-zoom">
                <div className="col-lg-12 project-detail-header">
                    <h2 className="name text-white">
   {this.state.project.name}</h2>
                    <hr className="split-line"/>
                    <h4 className="skills text-white">
   {this.state.project.description}</h4>
                    <h4 className="skills text-black">Developed 
   With</h4>
                    <h4 className="skills text-white">
   {this.state.project.tech}</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

        )
}
```

The router will not work well, only the first click will route to my page. Anyone can explain to me why does that happen?

Comment: I don't see a closing brace for the React component

Comment: no, there are no error, I did not put entire code here, bu i am sure there is no error

Comment: The thing is when I use const...it works fine. When I use class XXX extends React.Component, it will not work.

Comment: Can you check the console for errors, Its not a problem, it should work. Did you check the closing parenthesis

Comment: it is clean in my console, and I am pretty sure code is fine

Comment: What happens, the url changes and you see a blank page or you see some error message, can you elaborate what exactly is the problem

Comment: When I use React.Component, after I click navigation, url changes, but page not navigating. However, When I use const XXX = () => { return ()}, navigation working fine

Comment: Can we see the complete code of your class component? Because there is nothing wrong in given code. Also I wonder from where the `project` variable comes in your functional component.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/lfjdhr123/personal_web_react), default is the working version, branch router-component is the thing with issue